# Initializing variables before for loops to use in for loops queston

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, initializing

I'm trying to get familiarized with for loops right now for school and and learning the syntax right now. I have a couple questions. If I am going to initialize variables in the loop how can I ask the user for them to input the variable values before they are in the for loop? Here is the code I have written for it so far.

Also my scanner won't work for me in this code. I've been working on it for little bit so I figure it might need a second look.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class forloop
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first of two numbers:");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        for(int num1 ; counter <= num2; counter ++)
        System.out.println("There are " + counter + " numbers between " + 
        num1 + " and " + num2);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the user's input into temporary variables and then inside your loops initialize the user's inputs to be those temporary variables.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class forloop
{
public static void main(String []args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter your first of two numbers:");
    int temp1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
    int num2 = input.nextInt();

    for(int num1 = temp1; counter <= num2; counter ++)
    System.out.println("There are " + counter + " numbers between " + 
    num1 + " and " + num2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest possible solution:

```
public class forloop
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first of two numbers:");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        for(int x = num1 ; counter <= num2; counter ++)
        System.out.println("There are " + counter + " numbers between " + 
        num1 + " and " + num2);
    }
}
```

In the first expression in a for loop, you need to declare the variable that is controlling the loop and assign it a value - num1 in your case. In the second expression, you need to put the condition on which the loop keeps iterating - I am not really sure what you meant by `counter`. The problem  is that this variable has not been declared. You need to declare it before you can use it. 
 What do you want your program to do?